# Adding section in breadcrumbs

Tags: navigation, sections

My Entry URL Format looks like this: `{section}/{slug}` and I am using the standard breadcrumbs code;

```
   {% if entry.level > 1 %}
    <ul class="crumbs">
        {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
            <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

This will parse:

```
Home > article > entry-title
```

how can you add the {section} in as:

```
Home > section name > article > entry-title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a more "magic" way than just hard coding the first list item/link, i.e. something like this:

```
{% if entry.level > 1 %}
    <ul class="crumbs">
        <li>
            <a href="/{{ entry.section.handle }}">{{ entry.section.name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
            <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```